# How to collect the event value every time the CUDA kernel function been invoked with nvprof?

Tags: cuda, nvprof

Profiling CUDA programs with nvprof.

I have discribed the problem in [How to collect the event value every time the kernel function been invocated?](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1037016/visual-profiler/how-to-collect-the-event-value-every-time-the-kernel-function-been-invocated-/)

I post the problem again.

With `nvprof --events tex0_cache_sector_queries --replay-mode kernel ./matrixMul`,

or  `nvprof --events tex0_cache_sector_queries --replay-mode application ./matrixMul`,

that we can collect the event values result:

```
==40013== Profiling application: ./matrixMul
==40013== Profiling result:
==40013== Event result:
"Device","Kernel","Invocations","Event Name","Min","Max","Avg","Total"
"Tesla K80 (0)","void matrixMulCUDA<int=32>(float*, float*, float*, int, int)",301,"tex0_cache_sector_queries",0,30,24,7224
```

Above result is a summary. The 301 times invocation value of **tex0_cache_sector_queries** invocated by kernel function matrixMulCUDA. It just has the **min, max, avg, total** value of the 301 times invocation, that is a summary result.

I want to collect the complete 301 times tex0_cache_sector_queries values which from every time the matrixMulCUDA been invoked. On the other hand, every time the kernel function matrixMulCUDA been invoked, I want to collect the tex0_cache_sector_queries event value. How to collect it?

Answer (score 1):

1 run with:

```
nvprof --pc-sampling-period 31 --print-gpu-trace --replay-mode application \
--export-profile application.prof --events tex0_cache_sector_queries ./matrixMul
```

2 import the *application.prof* into visual profiler:

[visual profiler result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vSOe.jpg)

3 follow the index on the picture that get the every invocation of event value of each kernel function.

4 the `--print-gpu-trace` parameter: **Print individual kernel invocations (including CUDA memcpy's/memset's) and sort them in chronological order. In event/metric profiling mode, show events/metrics for each kernel invocation** can fix this problem. [print-gpu-trace](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#gpu-trace-and-api-trace-modes)